# H2 DB CSVWRITE Duplicate Double Quotes Inside a String

Tags: database, csv, h2

I was trying to export a table in `H2` DB into CSV using `CSVWRITE` function and found out if double quotes are included in a `varchar` column they will be duplicated.

Eg. - `'hello"howareyou' will be 'hello""howareyou' in the written csv.`

Tried saving this varchar column with escape characters and few other combinations but result is the same.

Following is my table column I created to test this issue and the resulted CSV value I got.

```
    My column         CSV written value
    ------------------------------
    hello"how         hello""how
    hello\"how        hello\""how
    hello""how        hello""""how
    hello\""how       hello\""""how
    hello\\"how       hello\\""how
    hello\\\\"how     hello\\\\""how
    hello["]how       hello[""]how
    hello&quote;how   hello&quote;how
```

Following is my CSVWrite command:

```
    CALL CSVWRITE(
      '#DELTA_CSV_DIR#/DELTA.csv', 
      'SELECT ccc from temptemp', 
      null,  '|',  '');
```

Am I doing this wrong? or is there any option or workaround I can use to avoid this situation?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are currently using [the built-in CSVWRITE function](http://h2database.com/html/functions.html#csvwrite) with the following options:

- fileName = '#DELTA_CSV_DIR#/DELTA.csv'
- query = 'SELECT ccc from temptemp'
- characterSet = default (UTF-8)
- fieldSeparator = '|'
- fieldDelimiter = '' (empty string)

[As documented, the default escape character is a double quote](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#csv_options), so that double quotes are escaped using a double quote (in the same way as you need to escape a backslash within a Java string with a backslash). The escape character is needed to escape the field separator.

You can disable the escape character as follows:

```
CALL CSVWRITE(
  '#DELTA_CSV_DIR#/DELTA.csv', 
  'SELECT ccc from temptemp', 
  'fieldSeparator=| fieldDelimiter= escape=');
```

This is also using the more readable new format for options.

Comment: Thank You @Thomas. It works.
FYI - was testing this on h2-1.2.140 and got an java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException. Upgraded to the latest, h2-1.3.171 and works.

Comment: You are right, version 1.2.140 doesn't support this feature yet.